# What is the meaning of scan count in SET STATISTICS IO ON?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I'm looking at the output of a query after running the following command: `SET STATISTICS IO ON`

Table1 shows scan count as 5, logical reads 12197

Table2 shows scan count as 0, logical reads 80

The documentation says

> scan count is the number of seeks or scans started after reaching the
> leaf level in any direction to retrieve all the values to construct
> the final dataset for the output.

I am looking for an example to understand what this (scan count) means with respect to the above output. My confusion is that how does logical reads of 12197 happen with only 5 scans?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the quote says, the number of scans is the number of scanning operations started by the database engine.

These scans might be a full scan of a table or index. They might be a forward or backward scan in index order after an initial seek, optionally with an end point as well.

The only thing not considered to be a type of scan in SQL Server is an equality seek on a single value into a unique index. This includes RID and Key Lookups, which are equality seeks to a single row by definition.

It might be difficult to think of an RID Lookup as a seek, but it really is directly locating a row using the file, page, and row number. There's no scan involved in an [RID Lookup](https://www.sql.kiwi/2011/02/seeking-without-indexes.html#rid-lookups).

Everything else has a scanning component as the engine checks for additional matching rows.

Clearly a scan might read more than one page.

A parallel scan (or seek with a range component) will generally show one scan per thread, plus one for the parent task distributing ranges to child workers. For example, a full scan at DOP 8 will show 9 scans.

Operators on the inner side of a nested loop may report more than one scan as they are closed and reopened on each new iteration.

See the following by Amit Banerjee on the Microsoft SQL Server Tips & Tricks blog:

- [SCAN COUNT meaning in SET STATISTICS IO output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlserverfaq/scan-count-meaning-in-set-statistics-io-output)
- [Scan Count meaning in SET STATISTICS IO output: Part 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlserverfaq/scan-count-meaning-in-set-statistics-io-output-part-2)

Also, my articles:

- [So…is it a Seek or a Scan?](https://www.sql.kiwi/2011/02/so-is-it-a-seek-or-a-scan.html)
- [Seeking Without Indexes](https://www.sql.kiwi/2011/02/seeking-without-indexes.html)

Answer (score 5):

Think of the scan count as an action. You had five actions to retrieve your 12,197 pages. Not seeing the execution plan, I'm just guessing, but let's assume a Nested Loops Join. There are five rows at the top of the join, so five times, the data access at the bottom of the join were done to retrieve the 12,197 pages. Each action, each scan, could be hitting the entire table, if, for example, you were seeing a clustered index scan on the bottom of the join. Therefore, five actions resulted in a lot of pages getting moved around.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [what Grant said](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/316839/22336), Logical Reads is just the number of data pages that were read from the Page Cache (Memory). It could be 1, 100, 1,000,000, any number, and there's not necessarily a direct correlation of that number to the number of Scans that occurred to load those data pages.

For example, if you had a really wide row that fully used a few `VARCHAR(MAX)` columns, that's going to be multiple GBs of data per each row in the Table. A data page only stores up to 8 KB of data. So a single row can use up hundreds of thousands of data pages in this example. If your query resulted in a single Scan to find all the rows of data, it would result in millions to billions of Logical Reads, for **one** scan.